# Why GCC produces huge executable comparing to VCC?

Tags: gcc, size, executable

I have a project that's not really big. With Visual Studio's C++ compiler the executable is 100+KB. But with mingw GCC it goes up to 500+ KB. Same thing happens on Linux. That's for the release build. For debug build GCC produces 1.4MB while VS's C++ compiler only produces 400+KB. What's the reason that causes such a huge discrepancy? Does it have anything to do with static/dynamic linking? What can I do to reduce the executable size produced by GCC?

Comment: If you're linking dynamically with MS Studio and statically with GCC it might be that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this page on how to shrink GCC output size: http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Reducing_Executable_Size

Answer (score 1):

- Did you pass the `-s` flag to GCC?
- Is Visual Studio linking with the CRT statically or dynamically? How about GCC? It's likely that VC is linking dynamically (`/MD` flag, instead of `/MT`) whereas GCC is linking statically (`-static-libgcc` flag, and otehrs)... try making them consistent and then seeing if there's a difference.

  One way to tell is to check if your VC-linked executable depends on `msvcr80.dll` (or a different version), and to see if your GCC-linked executable depends on some `mingw` DLL. If they do, then they're dynamically linked; if they truly run standalone, then they're statically linked.

Comment: I cannot check my VC build flags for now. I did try the -shared-libgcc though. It didn't have any effect.